# AWS Push notification flow and SDK for swift 3

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, swift3

I am new to iOS developement, i wanted to do push notification with AWS SNS.How to do that? guide me, how can i get sdk or pod file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you are able to obtain a p12 certificate for push from Apple you can upload this into MobileHub (an AWS service) to create an app that will work with AWS SNS. https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub

Answer (score 0):

You can get some basic idea by reading [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html). I can give you some brief procedure,

1. Create app in Xcode.
2. Create profile, certificate for app and APNS
3. Configure your app with AWS SNS.